# how can I put null check in conditional block when using optional in java?

Tags: java, option-type

this is the code

```
Optional<Buyer> buyerOptional = Optional.ofNullable(buyerRepository.findById(buyerId).orElse(null));
Buyer buyer = buyerOptional.get();
if (buyer != null) {
    
} else if (buyerOptional == null) {
    response = utility.createResponse(500, KeyWord.ERROR, "Invalid buyer");
}
```

I want to get inside else if block, would be great if I could get any suggestion on this.

Comment: The whole point of `Optional` return type of repository was to avoid that `null`, which you've introduced and tumbled further upon yourself. The complete picture isn't really shown depicted in the question, but generally with proper abstraction its fairly straightforward to use .map(.<to actual response here>.).orElse*(.<default response here>.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create `Optional` again as `findById` already return `Optional`. And you can use `isPresent()` to check if value present or not.

```
Optional<Buyer> buyerOptional = buyerRepository.findById(buyerId);
if (buyerOptional.isPresent()) {
   Buyer buyer = buyerOptional.get();
   ... // preparing response
} else {
    response = utility.createResponse(500, KeyWord.ERROR, "Invalid buyer");
}
```

Comment: @Naman As I don't know about the operation for response processing and if multiple statements used in response processing it's better to use if-else I think.